# FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have found a specific case when `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("tag")` returns `null`.

I have a gut feeling it has to do with timing?

I have a networking library with the following callbacks:

```
onStart()
{
    Utils.ShowLoadingDialog("loading");
}

onFinnish()
{
    Utils.DismissLoadingDialog("loading");
}
```

Then in my Utils class I have the following code:

```
public void showLoadingDialog(String title, String message, String tag) {
        DialogFragment loadingDialogFragment = new LoadingDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(CommonBundleAttributes.CONNECTING_ACTIVITY_DIALOG_TITLE, title);
        args.putString(CommonBundleAttributes.CONNECTING_ACTIVITY_DIALOG_MESSAGE, message);
        loadingDialogFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction  = fragManager.beginTransaction();
        loadingDialogFragment.show(transaction, tag);
    }

public void dismissLoadingDialog(String tag) {
        DialogFragment dg = (DialogFragment) fragManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (dg != null) {
            // this reference isn't null so the dialog is available
            dg.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }
```

Now this generally works fine. However in cases when the network layer detects there is no internet. It will throw an error and then immediately call `onFinnish()`. In this case the `Utils.DismissDialog(tag)` does nto find the fragment and therefore does not dismiss it?

Comment: Are you doing the network call before or immediately after you call `showLoadingDialog(...)`? If so your gut feeling might be correct, i.e. your network library throws an error on its thread before the last line of `showLoadingDialog` has executed (assuming it is on another thread).

Comment: I think you are having a [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) Imho you should test if there is internet before showing the wrong dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`executePendingTransactions()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions()) to wait for the fragment transaction to come through.

```
public void dismissLoadingDialog(String tag) {
        fragManager.executePendingTransactions();
        DialogFragment dg = (DialogFragment) fragManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (dg != null) {
            // this reference isn't null so the dialog is available
            dg.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solved the problem.  I'm not sure if its the correct thing to do design wise. However I did some reading and `.commit()` is an async operation. Meaning that the fragment manager will load the transaction when it has time to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Use TRY-CATCH or even IF statement to check current internet-connection.

Answer (score 0):

This can be case with the committing the transaction.
Just check if in your show method if you have commit the transaction for Dialog fragment or not.

```
transaction.commit();
```

Until that your fragment manager does not have fragment to be added in that.

Also you need to make sure you are finding fragment from same Activity's fragment manager to which you committed fragment.